# Interviewstreet- Permutation Game

Tags: algorithm, math, game-theory

Alice and Bob play the following game:

1) They choose a permutation of the first N numbers to begin with.

2) They play alternately and Alice plays first.

3) In a turn, they can remove any one remaining number from the permutation.

4) The game ends when the remaining numbers form an increasing sequence. The person who played the last turn (after which the sequence becomes increasing) wins the game.

Assuming both play optimally, who wins the game?

Input:
The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. Each case contains an integer N on the first line, followed by a permutation of the integers 1..N on the second line.

Output:
Output T lines, one for each test case, containing "Alice" if Alice wins the game and "Bob" otherwise.

**Sample Input:**

2

3

1 3 2

5

5 3 2 1 4

**Sample Output:**

Alice

Bob

**Constraints:**

1 <= T <= 100

2 <= N <= 15

The permutation will not be an increasing sequence initially.

I am trying to solve above problem. I have derived till far but I am stuck at a point. Please help me to proceed further.

In above problem, for permutation of length 2, player 1 always wins.

For a permutation of length 3, player 2 wins if the string is strictly increasing or decreasing.

For a permutation of length 4, If player 1 is able to make the string strictly increasing or decreasing by removing a character, she wins else player 2 wins.

Hence a conclusion is:

If current player is able to make the string strictly increasing he/she wins. (Trivial case)

If he/she is able to make it strictly decreasing the the winner is decided by the number of elements in that sequence. If there are even number of elements in that sequence, current player looses, else wins.

But what should be done if the resultant string is neither increasing nor decreasing??

Comment: Is this homework? Asking homework questions isn't a bad thing, but if this is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: I don't have any advice I can give you, but for this type of problem it might be worth checking out the books ["Games of No Chance"](http://library.msri.org/books/Book29/contents.html) and ["More Games of No Chance"](http://library.msri.org/books/Book42/), which deal with this kind of "full information" game. The books contain many proofs about who can win two player games like this, and under what conditions, so they might be worth looking at for inspiration if nothing else.

Comment: This problem requires basics of algorithm games. You can read about it on [Topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=algorithmGames). For this problem, I think you might also need to use memoizaion. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Thanks for replying. I'm not able to figure out if a question if a homework problem or not! How to? I was trying to solve it and couldn't get around so decided to find some help. :) Thank you for the valuable resources you mentioned. :)

Comment: @PriyankBhatnagar I have already gone through that tutorial! Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @LoginTest: Decent chunks of those books are available for free on Google Books. That's how I found them. ;)

Answer (score 9):

This is a typical game problem. You have 2^15 possible positions which denote which are the remaining numbers. From the number of the remaining numbers you can derive whose turn it is. So now you have a graph that is defined in the following manner - the vertices are the possible sets of remaining numbers and there is an edge connecting two vertices u and v iff there is a move that changes set u to set v(i.e. set v has exactly one number less).

Now you already pointed out for which positions you know who is the winner straight away - the ones that represent increasing sequences of numbers this positions are marked as loosing. For all other positions you determine if they are wining or loosing in the following manner: a position is winning iff there is an edge connecting it to a loosing position. So all that is left is to something like a dfs with memoization and you can determine which positions are winning and which are loosing. As the graph is relatively small (2^15 vertices) this solution should be fast enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try to do it the way you mentioned though its different from what I was thinking. If I reach any conclusion in my approach I'll post in here as answer. :)

Comment: Noting the number of sets of remaining numbers (which is far smaller than the number of permutations) is a useful observation.  I would suggest, though, that a graph-based solution is perhaps overcomplicated.  Instead, I would simply keep track, for each combination of remaining numbers, whether there exists a winning move.  A set of numbers is considered to have a winning move if both (1) the remaining numbers are not in order, and (2) there exists at least one of the remaining numbers such that removing it would leave the opponent in a losing position.

Comment: If one examines all the combinations which have two numbers remaining, then three, then four, etc. one will eventually reach the combination in which all the numbers remain.  If there exists a winning move for that combination, the first player wins.  Otherwise the second player wins.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, this can be done with "brute force" for small N, but don't you suspect an easier answer around [inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) and [the sign of a permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation)?

Originally I suspected an answer like "Alice wins iff the sign is -1, else loses", but this is not the case.

But I would like to propose a representation of the problem that not only your algorithm may use, but one that will equally boost your paper-and-pen performance in this game.

An inversion is a pair of indices i<j such that a[i]>a[j]. Consider (`i`,`j`) an edge of an undirected graph with vertices 1,...,N. Each player deletes a vertex from this graph and wins if there are no edges left.

For `5 3 2 1 4`, the resulting graph is

```
   5--3
  /|\ |
 / | \|
4  1--2
```

and Alice quickly sees that removing "5" gives Bob the opportunity to remove 2. Then no inversions are left, and Bob wins.

Answer (score 2):

This game can be solved recursively.

Each time alice takes her first pick and picks i, subtract 1 from all the remaining numbers that are larger than i. Now we have the same game but with the numbers 1 to N-1

lets say your sequence is

1,3,5,4,2

on her first move, Alice can pick any number.
case1:
she picks 1, alice can win if bob cant win with 3,5,4,2 (equivalently 2,4,3,1)

case2:
she picks 3 first. Alice can win if bob cant win with 1,5,4,2 (equivalently 1,4,3,2)

case3:
she picks 5 first. Alice can win if bob cant win with 1,3,4,2

you get the idea.

So you can make a recursive function to work out the solution for a size N permutation all by using size N-1 permutations for each possible first guess. the base case for the recursion is when you have an in-order sequence.

Each step of the recursion, the person tries all possibilities and picks any that makes them win.

Because there are many combinations of moves that can get down to the same sequence, the recursion has overlapping sub problems. This means we can use dynamic programming, or simply "memoize" our function, greatly increasing efficiency.

For further speedup one may use symmetry in the permutations, as many groups of permutations are equivalent, such as the reverse of one permutation would yield the same result.

Good luck.

Comment: also you can use the bits of an integer to represent the permutation. 15 bits.

Answer (score 1):

@tiwo ,@rup COnsidering 5 3 2 1 4 is the sequence first alice removes 5 and the bob removes 2 then the sequence is 3 1 4 which is not in increasing order then alice gets the chance to remove 1 and the the sequence is in ascending order Alice should be the answer. In the graph you gave there should be an edge between  3 and 1 as 1 and 3 are in inversion.

Please tell me where i am wrong as the answer given in the problem is infact BOB

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with minimax algorithm. Here is the code in java

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*;  
import java.math.*;  
import java.util.regex.*;  

public class Solution {  

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int t = ni();  
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++){  
            int n = ni();  
            Map<Long, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();  
            int[] numbers = new int[n];  
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){  
                numbers[j] = ni();  
            }  
            if(aliceWin(numbers, map)) System.out.println("Alice");  
            else System.out.println("Bob");  
        }  
    }  

    public static boolean aliceWin(int[] a, Map<Long, Boolean> map){  
        long h = hashCode(a); int temp;   
        if(map.containsKey(h)) return true;  

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){  
            if(a[i]>0){  
                temp = a[i] ;  
                a[i] = 0;  
                if(isIncreasing(a)){  
                    map.put(h, true);  
                    a[i] = temp;  
                    return true;  
                }  
                if(!aliceWin(a, map)) {  
                    map.put(h, true);  
                    a[i] = temp;  
                    return true;  
                }  
                a[i] = temp;  
            }  
        }  
        return false;  
    }  

    public static long hashCode(int[] a){  
        long result = 0;  
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){  
            result = (result << 4) + a[i];  
        }  
        return result;  
    }  
    public static boolean isIncreasing(int[] a){  
        int last = 0;  
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){  
            if (a[i] > 0){  
                if(last > a[i]) return false;  
                last = a[i];  
            }  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  
    public static int ni(){  
        return sc.nextInt();  
    }  

    public static void print(Object... args){          
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(args));  
    }  
}
```

From blog: [hackerrank-permutation-game](http:///2015/12/hackerrank-permutation-game.html)

Comment: why does updating the array before returning change anything when the array isn't global

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that builds the graph for you, but requires you to call reverse() on the graph, create a source node connecting to all nodes in the base, flow back to source seeing if there is a way alice wins.

```
input_ = """2

3

1 3 2

5

5 3 2 1 4""".splitlines()

perms = [map(int,perm.split()) for perm in input_ if len(perm)>1]
"[['1', '3', '2'], ['5', '3', '2', '1', '4']]"

if networkx is None:
    import networkx
from itertools import combinations

def build_graph(perm):
    base = set()
    G = networkx.DiGraph()
    for r in range(1,len(perm)+1):
        for combo in combinations(perm,r):
            combo = list(combo)
            if combo == sorted(combo):
                base.add(tuple(combo))
                continue
            for i in range(r):
                G.add_edge(tuple(combo),tuple(combo[:i]+combo[i+1:])) #you may want to reverse the graph later to point from base to source.
    return G,base


def solve(G,base):
    #dfs,
    pass

for perm in perms:
    G,base = build_graph(perms[0])
    print solve(G,base)
```

Answer (score -1):

can't we just check at each step that..
does a single change by the next player makes the sequence sorted.. if yes then make some other move..
or carry on with the move

like
5 3 2 1 4
if alice does 3 2 1 4
bob cannot win in a single turn by eliminating any...
like if 
he does 2 1 4 it is nt sorted..
he does 3 1 4 it is nt sorted..
he does 3 2 4 it is nt sorted..
so 5 3 2 1 4 -> 3 2 1 4 is a valid move!!

now is bob's turn..
he'll check the same..
but in some time..there won't be a number such that u can make a move as above..
so u'll have to make a random move and who will win then can be easily calculated by the number of steps tht will make the sequence into single element!!

Answer (score -2):

To me (using almost your own words):

If he/she is able to make it strictly increasing on the first move he/she wins (Trivial case) otherwise the the winner is decided by the number of elements in that sequence.

Take your second case as example.

I think that the graph solution is fine but it forgets that the players play in a optimal way. So don't need to check all the different path since some of them will derive from a non-optimal choice.